# Know when windows ask to close a process

Tags: c#, windows

I want to watch a process (in another application) that might fail and relaunch it if it fail. It's working if the process is exited. But if the window that say the programe not seem to respond terminate now or wait is open.

My process is dead but as long as i don't click on close program i don't get any information about this.

My process are on multiple VM it's a process that update my client application and i try to not force my support to connect in every client to click on Close program every time a little bug happend.

Is their any event that can tell me window ask to close this process?

Is their a way to achive this? Right know I'm thinking about making a ping with my process using some message. But i would like a solution that don't involve modify both app and only the watcher app. Plus i'm not sure if a process is in "Close now" State have all thread stop or if my read message thread will continu to respond while my main thread will be dead.

Comment: Process.Responding Property "*Gets a value indicating whether the user interface of the process is responding*" then Process.Kill Method.

Comment: Seem like exactly what i need. I gonna chck this

Comment: Bear in mind, @TheGeneral answer requires that the process has a user interface (e.g. WinForms, or WPF), and will probably not work if the process is a console app.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is what you're asking, but I believe the standard way to check whether an application is responding to messages is to send a `WM_NULL` message to its top-level window with `SendMessageTimeout` and see if it responds within the timeout, say 10 seconds.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Reading the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.responding?view=netcore-3.1 I suspect that is exactly how it is implemented.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError pretty spot on, the source for responding   `responding = NativeMethods.SendMessageTimeout(new HandleRef(this, mainWindow), NativeMethods.WM_NULL,..`